# Selenium Python Can't click button: ElementNotInteractable or StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate MS Teams and can't get past the login because after entering the password I am having issues clicking the Sign In button.

If I try:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]')
button.click()
```

I get:

ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable.

If I try to solve it with Action Chains method (which seems to have solved many similiar issues for lots of people):

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
```

I get:

StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

It is worth mentioning that when logging in manually I can get past this stage with pressing return after entering my password but I couldn't be successful with send keys methods neither.

Comment: What error you get with `send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`..??

Comment: i don't get any errors or any results at all

Comment: well, have you already tried `submit` ? As the answer says?

Comment: yes and it got me yet another error.

Comment: Yea...I don't think one can do much without the actual link

Comment: I have supposed that you already found the input and entered password - So also provide code how you performed search for input, please.

Comment: `passwordInput = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="i0118"]')
passwordInput.send_keys('password')
passwordInput.submit()`

Comment: I can watch the code run and it seems to have no issues entering the password. If I leave the code just there, without the submit code, I can just click sign in and go on to do my thing.

Comment: @yokartikcem Stupid question I know, but is the password correct? As you mentioned below my answer: "website says: login parameter is empty or not valid"

Is there an url for us as AbrarAhmed mentioned?

Comment: yes I'm positive the password is correct. The URL is too long but you can get to the page after clicking sign in on this link: https://www.microsoft.com/en/microsoft-365/microsoft-teams/group-chat-software

Answer (score 0):

If you still filled the form use `submit()` function - It is there to make your life easier.

Import webdriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

Create webdriver object:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Get the website:

```
driver.get("https://www.YOUR_WEBSITE.de/")
```

Get element - In your case input for password

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="i0118"]')
```

Send keys - Enter password

```
element.send_keys("YOUR_PASSWORD")
```

Submit contents

```
element.submit()
```

Comment: This gets me "NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element" and the website seems to give some errors too. If I take out the part of my code clicking the button, no errors with the code but the website says: login parameter is empty or not valid.

Answer (score 0):

The element which you are trying to locate using the XPath `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]')` might be the part of the previous screen and new screen, hence the driver might be referring to the element which is part of the previous screen, hence you are getting the StaleElementReferenceException.

The simplest way to resolve this is you can add, `driver.refresh()` just before the above xpath, this will load the page and DOM with the new elements.

Else, you can use a different locator strategy which will uniquely identify that element.